# Change the style dynamically with bootswatch-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, bootswatch

I want to change my style using bootswatch-rails.

First, I would  install bootswatch-rails gem and change the files' extension to scss.erb. So then, i would wite in the file scss.erb:

```
<% theme = Themes.find(1) %>
```

Until here everything works fine but when i am navigating the style would suddenly change by itself. I think this could happen because the assets are stored in the momory or cache. So, i dont know how to do it or even if it is possible to get it done.

Comment: Why dont you just download the css file for that theme and place it in your stylesheets? You dont always have to use a gem, stick to only using 4-6 per application

Comment: Thanks. This option works well but i dont want to use it because i would have only 4-6 themes and i would like to have all themes of www.bootswatch.com, ANOTHER SOLUTION, PLEASE?